# AWS Cognito authorize endpoint returns 404

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am trying to access aws cognito authorize endpoint in browser and postman but getting response as 404 (File or directory not found.). Aws cognito configured with AZURE as IDP.
Azure active directory have MFA enable. Can anyone please let me know the root cause of this problem ? Attaching screenshots for reference.[image]

Cognito Endpoint :
https://<>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=<>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://<>/oauth2/idpresponse